# How to change in IIS Logging Fields?

Tags: iis, logging, server, iis-logs

I once enable the default filed in **IIS Logging**.

But the after I need to change and add other fields for **Logging**.

How to full **Disabled Logging** in IIS and Then after How to set as a new.

[image: Please refer to this image.]

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are asking, please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to let the IIS add the logs as with the new fields setting  for the previous logs?

In my opinion, this is impossible. The IIS logs will just log for the new field after you modified the fields. It will not keep the previous logs fields value.